# How to handle decimal ncr characters in php

Tags: php, html, unicode

I have a title of the document which is having the decimal ncr characters it needs to be converted to HTML.I tried mb_decode_numericentity but its not working, is there any other function which needs to be used.

```
Zasíláme Vám Set Eduka&#269;ních Materiál&#367;, Kterými Chceme P&#345;isp&#283;t k Minimalizaci Rizik Podávání Biologického Léku Remsima (infliximab)
```

Comment: If “ncr” means numeric character reference, like `&#225;` for “á”, then they *are* HTML. So what do you mean by converting them to HTML?

Comment: They are displaying correctly on the html page but when I am writing them in pdf they are coming wrong, they are not converting to czech characters.

Comment: So how are you generating the PDF file? How are they “coming wrong”? Why did you tag the question with “php” (I don’t see any PHP code) but not with “pdf”?

Comment: I m using fpdf reader to write the title in the pdf but when i download the pdf it comes as those numbers not their associated value of czech

Answer (score 1):

`mb_decode_numericentity` is a weird function. In an attempt to make it match the interface for `mb_encode_numericentity`, there is a `$convmap` function that specifies which code points you want converted, and if omitted it defaults to no code points at all (do nothing). Also the default charset is probably not anything sensible.

To make it do something:

```
$convmap = array(0x0, 0x1FFFFF, 0, 0x1FFFFF);
mb_decode_numericentity($s, $convmap, 'utf-8')
```

However note that it doesn't decode HTML builtin entity references like `&amp;` so as a means of decoding HTML content it's pretty much useless. Closer is:

```
html_entity_decode($s, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

or easiest, use an HTML parser to load the page and extract the already-decoded data from the DOM.

Comment: $o="Zasíláme Vám Set Edukačních Materiálů, Kterými Chceme Přispět k Minimalizaci Rizik Podávání Biologického Léku Remsima (infliximab)";
$s="Zasíláme Vám Set Eduka&#269;ních Materiál&#367;, Kterými Chceme P&#345;isp&#283;t k Minimalizaci Rizik Podávání Biologického Léku Remsima (infliximab)";

html_entity_decode($s, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
echo 'Original String:'.$o.'<br/>';
echo $s;

I tried the above code still its not working

Comment: ZasÃ­lÃ¡me VÃ¡m Set EdukaÄnÃ­ch MateriÃ¡lÅ¯, KterÃ½mi Chceme PÅ™ispÄ›t k Minimalizaci Rizik PodÃ¡vÃ¡nÃ­ BiologickÃ©ho LÃ©ku Remsima (infliximab)

It gives above output can you see the wrong characters

Comment: Your browser is displaying the output using the wrong encoding. Choose UTF-8 from your View->Encoding menu, or include a `<meta charset="utf-8">` or `Content-Type` charset in the response to tell the browser what it's looking at and you will see the correct output.

Comment: No the main thing is browser is displaying it correctly, I m writing this title into pdf and when i open the pdf is displays those characters, can you please let me know how to fix.

Comment: Getting non-ASCII characters into PDF is a separate question really, it will depend on what you're using to create PDFs (tcpdf, fpdf, ...?)

Comment: HTMLtoPDF is used to do this

Comment: You probably need `$unicode=true, $encoding='UTF-8'` in the HTML2PDF constructor. If that doesn't work suggest posting a new question as it's not to do with HTML-decoding and I don't know anything about HTML2PDF.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I m using fpdf for pdf generation and in its constructor I have added those two $unicode and $encoding.

Comment: Ah I think for fpdf you would need to use tFPDF.

Comment: tFPDF is a different pdf generator which I should use to replace existing FPDFreader asper you